# Laravel: response format based on a a route prefix

Tags: php, laravel

I have some routes in my Laravel application (many routes)

I want to add new functionality, to return all data in JSON format. Now data are just views .

/route1/options
/route2/options

etc

i want to have

/json/route1/options
/json/route2/options

so, if any my existent route gets a prefix /json then data should be returned with JSON .

My routes looks like normal routes in Laravel

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id) {

    $user = ....
    return view('userprofile', $user);
});
```

How to change this to know that json format is requested? 
should it be separate routing group where each route is described again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes the best way to achieve this would be to allow the client to choose what they want. This is typically achieved using the Accept header.

```
GET myapp.com/user/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept application/json
```

This method is good when writing applications in Laravel as the request object is always informed if JSON is requested via the Accept header.

*I've used Laravel 5.2's implicit model binding in the following examples.*

```
Route::get('user/{user}', function(Request $request, User $user) {

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    return view('userProfile', $user);
});
```

This method avoids putting unnecessary information in the url keeping your API clean. However a route that many go down (myself included) is to separate routes that return data and routes that return views.

```
Route::get('user/{user}', function(Request $request, User $user) {
    // Standard route, return a view
});

Route::get('api/user/{user}', function(Request $request, User $user) {
    // API route, always return JSON
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Laravel 5.2:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{format?}', function($id, $format = null) {

    $user = ....

    if($format == 'json') {
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    return view('userprofile', $user);
});
```